# Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity

How do I `auto increment` the `primary key` in a `SQL Server` database table? I've had a look through the forum but can't see how to do this.

I've looked at the properties but can't see an option. I saw an answer where you go to the `Identity` specification property and set it to yes and set the `Identity increment` to **1**, but that section is grayed out and I can't change the *no* to *yes*.

There must be a simple way to do this but I can't find it.

Comment: Is the key column's datatype is int?

Comment: @CoDe aDDict its currenty set as char(10) but i can change it as I'm just practicing , thanks

Answer (score 883, accepted):

Make sure that the Key column's datatype is `int` and then setting identity manually, as image shows

[image]

Or  **just run this code** utilizing [IDENTITY(seed, increment)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16) modifier

```
-- ID is the name of the  [to be] identity column
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] DROP COLUMN ID 
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

the code will run, if `ID` is not the  only column in the table

*image reference fifo's*

Comment: Just a bit of correction: The `IDENTITY` property could be applied to any numeric data types (so it could be `tinyint`, `smallint`, `int`, `bigint`, `numeric`, `decimal`), the only constraint is that it could not represent fractional number (so it **can't be** `float` or `real`, neither `numeric` or `decimal` *with non-zero scale*) and ofc, the identity spec should be compatible with the selected data type.

Comment: Work's, providing there are no Foreign keys etc

Comment: I just wanted to add, if you've already set a default value on your identity column, the (Is Identity) remains greyed out. Remove the default value, and it becomes available again.

Comment: If you can't modify the values, go to Tools-Options-Designers and uncheck the option "prevent saving changes that require a re-creation".

Comment: Why is it even named "identity"? It's kinda a really abstract way of describing an autoincremented value.

Comment: @carloswm85 Because the field generally *identifies* the record you are looking at.

Answer (score 261):

When you're creating the table, you can create an [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) column as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE (
  ID_column INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);
```

The `IDENTITY` property will auto-increment the column up from number 1. (Note that the data type of the column has to be an integer.) If you want to add this to an existing column, use an [`ALTER TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command.

Edit:
Tested a bit, and I can't find a way to change the Identity properties via the Column Properties window for various tables. I guess if you want to make a column an identity column, you HAVE to use an `ALTER TABLE` command.

Comment: Ah, this is for SQL Server 2008 r2 specifically - never mind.

Comment: this create table syntax is **good practice** as advised by author of  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4862427/2218697) post in comments, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 102):

You have to expand the Identity section to expose increment and seed.

[image]

Edit: I assumed that you'd have an integer datatype, not char(10). Which is reasonable I'd say and valid when I posted this answer

Comment: The `yes` is greyed out as it is `char(10)` (from comment just posted)

Comment: @Martin Smith yes that seems to be the general issue , I'm going to change this and test, many thanks

Comment: while creating a new table i used `BookID int primary key identity` i didn't specify both seed and increment , is that good practice ? cause i see documentation in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) If neither is specified, the default is (1,1) .

Answer (score 48):

Expand your database, expand your table right click on your table and select **design** from dropdown.
[image: ITlooks like this]

Now go **Column properties** below of it scroll down and find **Identity Specification**, expand it and you will find **Is Identity** make it Yes. Now choose **Identity Increment** right below of it give the value you want to increment in it.
[image]

Answer (score 19):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int
);
```

The MS SQL Server uses the IDENTITY keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

In the example above, the starting value for IDENTITY is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

Tip: To specify that the "Personid" column should start at value 10 and increment by 5, change it to IDENTITY(10,5).

To insert a new record into the "Persons" table, we will NOT have to specify a value for the "Personid" column (a unique value will be added automatically):

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps I'm missing something but why doesn't this work with the SEQUENCE object?  Is this not what you're looking for?

Example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA blah.
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE blah.blahsequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO CYCLE;

CREATE TABLE blah.de_blah_blah
(numbers bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
......etc
```

When referencing the squence in say an INSERT command just use:

```
NEXT VALUE FOR blah.blahsequence
```

More information and options for [SEQUENCE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Comment: This solution is the correct one if you care about the time order of inserted rows, because `IDENTITY` sometimes jumps leaving gaps then it is back to fill those gaps again. So `IDENTITY` does not guarantee ALWAYS incrmenet condition

Comment: @Martin Smith Oops, didn't follow the link, my mistake! I've gotten so used to MS-SQL not having certain features that I sometimes forget that there are newer versions that support more stuff. I'll delete my comment since it might be confusing... If expressed more general it remains valid though: could be that he's using an RDBMS make/version that doesn't support SEQUENCE objects -- especially since the question was asked only a few months after SQL Server 2012 was released ;)

Comment: @FindOut_Quran Are you sure that gaps in IDENTITY columns are filled up? I've only worked with SQL Server 2005 where I've never seen that happen - the gaps simply remain. And I'd be rather surprised to see it happen on any RDBMS because such a feature would be a strange combination of "not free" (performance-wise) and "not desirable" (at least in most applications).

Comment: @PaulGroke Yes I am sure. You can try be using a transaction for inserting 1000 rows, then rollback. The idenetity value will jumb up. Try to insert more thousands of rows and commit / or rollback. You will notice it sometimes backs to fill gaps

Comment: @FindOut_Quran I can not see how this could happen. MS SQL IDENTITY columns use a simple counter which is seeded at a user-definable value and then incremented by a user-definable value. You can even query and re-set the counter. The only way I can see this happening is when concurrent transactions commit "out of order". I.e. the transaction that was *first* bumping the IDENTITY counter commits *after* another transaction. In that case you'd have a short-lived gap that then gets filled up. Which is necessary to avoid collisions. The IDENTITY counter will never have jumped back though.

Comment: @PaulGroke Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/14642085/3441905  and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database

Comment: @FindOut_Quran OK, this explains nicely how large gaps can be created. I cannot find anything in there though that would explain how, or even suggest that they are filled up later. Except for the situation that I already described, i.e. multiple in flight transactions committing "out of order".

Answer (score 7):

When you're using Data Type: int you can select the row which you want to get autoincremented and go to the column properties tag. There you can set the identity to 'yes'. The starting value for autoincrement can also be edited there. Hope I could help ;)

Comment: where is the column properties located at?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue where I had already **created the table** and could not change it without dropping the table so what I did was:
(Not sure when they implemented this but had it in SQL 2016)

Right click on the table in the Object Explorer:

`Script Table as > DROP And CREATE To > New Query Editor Window`

Then do the edit to the script said by Josien; scroll to the bottom where the `CREATE TABLE` is, find your Primary Key and append `IDENTITY(1,1)` to the end before the comma. Run script.

The DROP and CREATE script was also helpful for me because of [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550488/drop-table-then-cannot-recreate-table-with-the-same-name) (Which the generated script handles.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keyword `IDENTITY` as the data type to the column along with `PRIMARY KEY` constraint when creating the table.
ex:

```
StudentNumber IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

In here the first '1' means the starting value and the second '1' is the incrementing value.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is already populated it is not possible to change a column to IDENTITY column or convert it to non IDENTITY column. You would need to export all the data out then you can change column type to IDENTITY or vice versa and then import data back.
I know it is painful process but I believe there is no alternative except for using sequence as mentioned in this post.

Comment: You can use `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` to just switch the metadata without having to touch the data at all. e.g. See [how to set auto increment after creating a table without any data loss?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6084572/73226)

Comment: Process mentioned in the link provided by you involves transferring the data to temp table and back which does agree with my statement above. If I am wrong please provide me a working example.

Comment: There's a working example in the link. There's no " transferring the data to temp table and back". ` ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` is a metadata only change. It doesn't move any data.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull like if you want the ID elements to be contigius or not. As SQLSERVER ID can jump by 1000 .

Examle: before restart   ID=11
after restart  , you insert new row in the table, then the id will be 1012.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following: New Table Creation:

```
-- create new table with Column ID which is Primary Key and Auto Increment --
    
CREATE TABLE titles(
      id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,  --Primary Key with Auto-Increment --
      keyword        VARCHAR(260),
      status VARCHAR(10),
 );
```

If you Table Already exists and need to make the changes to ID column to be auto-increment and Primary key, then see below:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN id; // drop the existing ID in the table 
ALTER TABLE table ADD id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL; // add new column ID with auto-increment
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ident_test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id); // make it primary key
```