# A gap between id which are autoincremented in db

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table in my db whose id is int auto increment. When I create a ndew entry everything goes well, the id is incremented by 1.

But today I saw a big hole. One of the records has id=56 and the next on has id=1055.

What could cause this. We didn't make backups on this db.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are there gaps in my IDENTITY column values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642013/why-are-there-gaps-in-my-identity-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that can cause this

1. someone reseeded the table by running `DBCC CHECKIDENT`
2. someone inserted a bunch of rows and deleted them
3. A batch of rows was attempted to be inserted, the batch failed,
   everything was rolled back, SQL Server does not reuse identity
   values

Also keep in mind, if you delete all the rows with a `DELETE` statement, the seed is not reset back to 1, if you `TRUNCATE` the table then it is

Comment: Can i somehow check if DBCC CHECKIDENT was executed on this db?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there had been some errors on insert, or transaction rollbacks. 
Identity value of a table is not affected by transaction. So for example, even if you insert a value into the table, and rollback the transaction, your indentity value will "stay incremented". Short example to illustrate:

```
create table _test (
    id int identity (1,1)
    ,txt varchar(2)
)
insert into _test(txt)
select 'aa' as txt

insert into _test(txt)
select 'bb' as txt union all 
select 'ccc'

GO

insert into _test(txt)
select 'dd' as txt


select * from _test
```