# Identity Key losing count after insert failure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

I am using MVC4 whit entity framework 5, when server return error of insert because the table have a unique e-mail, I dont wanna lose id numbers. I need to check if this e-mail exists before try insert or entity framework have any another way to cover any failure error and reset the Identity Seed counter. Thanks

Comment: Why do you not want to lose numbers? An `IDENTITY` column does not guarantee consecutive numbers, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642013/why-are-there-gaps-in-my-identity-column-values) and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Comment: Identify values increment even for a failed insert *by design*, so that identity inserts can be done concurrently.  There should be no reason why you need your identity values to be sequential - they should serve only as a unique identifier.  If you do need a sequential numbering of your rows, you can determine this at query time using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: I am warning about bigint get max number before the number of rows is completed. So to know too, looking for good practices.

Comment: Ehh, do I get this well, you ran out of available numbers for bigint? (9,223,372,036,854,775,807). Anyway, [IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is a convenient method in this scenario.

Comment: The maximum `bigint` value is [2^63-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx), are you really worried about reaching that limit? The best practice is to simply to use identity values without worrying about what they are; they're just key values that have no meaning of their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in [this article](http://sqlity.net/en/792/the-gap-in-the-identity-value-sequence/), there is no way to prevent gaps in the identity generated numbers, one of the main reasons;

> To implement the identity value management transactional, a session
>   would need to take a lock on the identity value itself for the
>   duration of the transaction. That would force all inserts to be
>   executed consecutively and concurrency would be practically
>   non-existent.

About the shortage on bigint values, in most cases your DB will face a great number of problems before that gets near to happen.

Hope this was helpful.