# Identity column value suddenly jumps to 1001 in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using Sql server 2012(Denali). I wonder why all identity column values start from 1001 and so on. At the beginning `Identity` column starts from 1,2 and so on and adding identity smoothly, but suddenly it jumps to 1001,1002 and onwards for all the table in the database containing identity column. What could be the reason? Please assist.

Comment: If you care about the numerical values assigned to an identity column, you're doing something *wrong*. You should treat identity values as opaque blobs that you just happen to be able to store in `int` (or other numeric types) columns.

Comment: Yes datatype for all those are `int`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Microsoft has changed the way they deal with identity values in SQL Server 2012 and as a result of this you can see identity gaps between your records after rebooting your SQL server instance or your server machine. There might be some other reasons for this id gaps, it may be due to automatic server restart after installing an update.

You can use below two choices

- Use trace flag 272
  o This will cause a log record to be generated for each generated identity value. The performance of identity generation may be impacted by turning on this trace flag.
- Use a sequence generator with the NO CACHE setting

  Setting Trace Flag 272 on SQL Server 2012 that you are expecting here
- Open "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
- Click "SQL Server Services" on the left pane
- Right-click on your SQL Server instance name on the right pane ->Default: SQL    Server(MSSQLSERVER)
- Click "Properties"
- Click "Startup Parameters"
- On the "specify a startup parameter" textbox type "-T272"
- Click "Add"
- Confirm the changes

Comment: Below is a quote from a Microsoft post replying to this id crisis issue on "connect":If you require the same identity generation semantics as previous versions of SQL Server there are two options available:
Use trace flag 272
=>This will cause a log record to be generated for each generated identity value.The performance of identity generation may be impacted by turning on this trace flag.

Comment: Use a sequence generator with the NO CACHE setting(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

=>This will cause a log record to be generated for each generated sequence value. Note that the performance of sequence value generation may be impacted by using NO CACHE.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you have the explanation in a comment to this connect item. [Failover or Restart Results in Reseed of Identity](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-failover-results-in-reseed-of-identity%5d#tabs)

> To boost the preformance for high end machines, we introduce
>   preallocation for identity value in 2012. And this feature can be
>   disabled by using TF 272 (then you will get the behaviour from
>   2008R2).
>
> The identity properties are stored separately in metadata. If a value
>   is used in identity and increment is called, then the new seed value
>   will be set. No operation, including Rollback, Failover, ..... can
>   change the seed value except DBCC reseed. Failover applies for the
>   table object, but no the identity object. So for failover, you can
>   call checkpoint before manual failover, but you may see gap for
>   unplanned cases. If gap is a concern, then I suggest you to use TF
>   272.
>
> For control manager shutdown, we have a fix for next verion (with
>   another TF). This fix will take care of most control manager shutdown
>   cases.

Comment: How to avoid this situation

Comment: @eraj enable TF 272 as described in a comment of the same connect item.

Comment: @eraj - as I said in a comment to your question, if you *care* about the numerical values, you're using `IDENTITY` wrong.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: No, the person who wrote the system 10+ years ago did it wrong... And I don't have a time machine.

Comment: i have a mild ocd, so jumping the primary key from 6 to 1001 can be frustrating for me

Comment: If the Identity should ever reach int.Max, will the 'overjumped' ids be used or will it be the end of the world?

Comment: @Davatar There is no automatic going back. Everything stops.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use sequence instead, sequence gives you 100% complete control, and is in many ways far superior in comparison to identity... 
Identity is just so damn easy and convenient

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

<s>As far as i know, when you do a insert with identity and fails, the identity is used anyway,</s> Verified

with sequence you can make it "fill" gaps using cycle.
Although, as Amy Barrett is pointing out this is created out of scope of the transaction.

There is a performance optimization when you are using cache that might be useful as well.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is reading this, the Microsoft page (linked in your answer) says _"Sequence numbers are generated outside the scope of the current transaction. They are consumed whether the transaction using the sequence number is committed or rolled back."_ under General Remarks, so I assume the sequence number is used regardless of insert success/failure.