# SQL Server : how to find startup parameters for t272

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

For the people who know about this stuff is the identity field sometimes skipping by 1,000 a reason for concern? I know that Microsoft has done this on purpose for SQL Server 2012 but I want to make sure that an issue won't arise in the future because of identity fields being to large, I'm thinking of adding T272 but do not know how big of a performance hit that might be

I have SQL Server 2012 and I am trying to locate 'Startup Parameters' so that I can add T272 which will stop the primary key from skipping which was described on this thread [Identity column value suddenly jumps to 1001 in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587094/identity-column-value-suddenly-jumps-to-1001-in-sql-server) however if you look at the picture below I do not see the option for startup parameters

[image: My Sql management]

This right here is how it is supposed to look; anyways I can get my screen to look like the one below??

[image]

Comment: I don't know why your screen differs. If you are using INT for the IDENTITY then look for max INT, it is 2,147,483,647. You also have BIGINT and guid. I think if you are worried about a few 1000 sequences being tacked on after a server restart here and there, then you should be using something other than INT for your PK.

Answer (score 1):

Take these steps:

1. Open "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
2. Click "SQL Server Services" on the left pane
3. Right-click on your SQL Server instance name on the right pane 
   -> Default: SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
4. Click "Properties"
5. Click "Startup Parameters"
6. On the "specify a startup parameter" textbox; type "-T272"
7. Click "Add"
8. Confirm the changes

Answer (score 0):

I realise this answer probably comes months too late, but I suspect your screen is different because you are either not authenticated as an administrative user, or because you are using the SQL Express edition.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this comes very late but googling I found this thread so maybe my comment may help another. If you connect to your SQL Server remotely you will not get these tabs/options, you must log into the SQL Server directly. I was stuck in the same place until I tried it directly.