# ID jumping Issue With MSSQL and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with MSSQL ID jumping feature.

My Requirement is like,I need to generate a sequence number say,starting from 1000 and increment one by one and my application is hosted in multiple servers and points to same DB.Multiple host are  balanced with Nginx.

For this, wrote an Entity Class with SequenceGenerator

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "IdSequence", 
sequenceName = " ID_GEN",  
allocationSize = 1)
public class Example implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = " IdSequence ")
    private long id ;

}
```

And it works fine. When I restarted the DB, the next ID is jumped to `current+1000`
To resolve this I add a hibernate property, and its work fine against the ID jumping.

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
```

The real problem now is already existing entities with Auto generation strategy has getting exception like

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table ‘USER' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

- Is there any way to resolve the ID jumping issue in JPA/Hibernate
- How  can I avoid the `IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF` if am going with
  same fix.

> Could you please suggest a better option to generate sequence number
>   that should be unique.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're experiencing is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587094/identity-column-value-suddenly-jumps-to-1001-in-sql-server), rather than anything related to Hibernate.

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, right-click on your instance name on the right pane and click Properties then Startup Parameters
On the "specify a startup parameter" enter `-T272` to set the 272 trace flag.

I get your confusion and frustration, but ultimately, you shouldn't really need to worry about what your next `identity` value will be.

There's also a closed [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-failover-results-in-reseed-of-identity%5D#tabs) post indicating that this is the way it is with some other possible workarounds.

Comment: thanks, my requirement is like Id should be sequence value stating from1000 and increment 1 by 1. I don't think its problem with JPA/Hibernate. But Its a technique by MSSQL, am concern about is there any way to control this

Comment: If this is a requirement, then one recommendation is to roll your own increment solution.  Create a table with an integer field.  Inside a transaction, on insert, increment the integer field by one, and select this value to use for your pseudo-identity field, then commit.  Otherwise - the integer data type can go to just beyond 2 billion - quite sufficient for most applications.  I'd recommend just going with it and let the database do what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

in sql server, you may not insert a value for an identity column unless you specify `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <yourTableName> ON` before your insert statement.