# SQL Server value closest to bigint.minvalue was changed when posted to frontend

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a table in SQL Server with a column of type `bigint` which is auto-increment by 1 and starts from -9223372036854775808. But I see my value is -9223372036854776000 at my web page built using Angular 17.

I traced my backend API and found it returned correct result. Could someone guide me to fix this problem?  Sorry about not knowing which key word I could use to search on the net to find ways to solve it.

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276076/why-does-my-auto-incremented-id-skip-numbers-in-sql-server ?

Comment: No.  I mean that the sequence value at front page is different from that in my back end.

Comment: Ah, because javascript's number type is a `double` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#number_type). So you would probably need to serialise the value as a string

Comment: If the issue is resolved then please add an answer and accept it, so that we don't waste our time opening and reading the question and reading the comments, only to find out that you don't need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Jeremy Lakeman's comment that guided me to make the sequence value as  a string to solve it!