# SQL sever, Make a existing column primary and set to auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have old SQL sever table with 5000 rows. It has a column called `OrderID` which has the data type `int`. But this table doesn't have a primary key and `OrderID` is not on the sorted order. Can you please tell me how can I make this `OrderID` column the primary key and make it auto increment

Comment: You cannot set the autoincrement for existing column. It is possible only in Compact edition, afaik.

Comment: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012

Comment: `old SQL sever table...`. What is the version of your SQL Server database?

Comment: You want the auto-incremented values to start from the maximum value of orderID currently in the table?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  If it's SQL 2012 or later, you could use a [SEQUENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) (with some other steps) to accomplish your goal.  Let me know if you need some further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add identity to an existing column.
Your best option is to create a new table with the same structure and an identity column, set `identity_insert on` and then copy your records from the old one into the new one.

Check out [this answer from the MS SQL Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032/how-to-alter-column-to-identity11?forum=transactsql)

Comment: This is a good solution for a small table, like the table the OP is working with.  Not so great for really large tables, though.  I'd consider a SEQUENCE instead for SQL 2012 or later.  If the SEQUENCE feature isn't avaliable, then perhaps a "temp" column (with the IDENTITY property) in the same table...

Comment: After looking more closely at the link you provided, I see the "temp" column is mentioned there as option #2.  That would get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add identity to existing column. Create a new column "new_OderId" , copy data from "OderId" column paste in "new_OderId" column.

#add new column to Order_table
alter table Order_table add new_OderId int

#copy data from OrderId to new_OrderId
update Order_table set new_OrderId=OderId

#drop OderId column
alter table Order_table drop column OrderId