# C# insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am kinda new to C# and .NET applications. I work with visual studio and have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
    [Id]    INT           NOT NULL,
    [Meno]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Datum] DATETIME      NULL,
    [Cas]   INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And now I have a simple insert

```
public void NahrajSkore(string cas)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cns)) 
            {
                con.Open();

                var inset = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table values(@name,@date,@res)", con);
                inset.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                inset.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                inset.Parameters.Add("@res", SqlDbType.Int);
                inset.Parameters["@name"].Value = _hrac.MenoHraca;
                inset.Parameters["@date"].Value = DateTime.Today;
                inset.Parameters["@res"].Value = int.Parse(cas);
                inset.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

BUt this method gives me error :

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'*

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `insert into [Table]` (very bad idea, by the way)

Comment: Don't use `Table` as a name for your table. Since you did, as you did in query, use `[Table]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Table` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL.

You should use it with square brackets like `[Table]`

> If a reserved word is already in use, you can avoid error messages by
>   surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets (`[ ]`). **However,
>   the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word**.

You can use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for `SqlCommand` as well and you can define and add values of your parameters in a single line like;

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(cns)) 
{
    using(var inset = new SqlCommand("Insert into [Table] values(@name,@date,@res)", con))
    {
         inset.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hrac.MenoHraca;
         inset.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today;
         inset.Parameters.Add("@res", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(cas);
         con.Open();
         inset.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```

Also specifying column names in your `SqlCommand` is always recommended like;

```
"Insert into [Table](NameColumn, DateColumn, ResColumn) values(@name,@date,@res)"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it also be better to [specify the column names](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm)?

Comment: @BCdotNET Exactly. Updated my answer.

Comment: Okay I updatet it like you say. But now it says about primary key being null. How can I change it using visual studio to make it auto-increment ?

Comment: @XOOLOOO You can't change it on Visual Studio. You can change it on SQL Server. Read [Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Comment: @SonerGönül Oh thanks for that, but actualy I can update this from Visual Studio so thanks :)

Comment: There is also a [`inset.Parameters.AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method which makes the syntax a little bit nicer.

Comment: @Oliver **No**. Please don't use `AddWithValue` method. It _may_ cause some unexpected problems. [Read Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @SonerGönül: Thanks for the enlightening. I will never recommend this again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `Table` is a reserved word in SQL :)
Try using another name for your table or use `[Table]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the different name for the table to resolve this issue.

For ex:
 
`using(var inset = new SqlCommand("Insert into Student values(@name,@date,@res)", con))`