# Issues with SQL Max function: "Incorrect syntax new the keyword 'SELECT' "

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to return the maximum value of a column + 1 but for some reason it doesn't want to work.

```
DECLARE @ID int;

SET @ID = SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM tbl;
```

I can't for the life of me see what is wrong.

It gives me the error of:

> incorrect syntax new the keyword 'SELECT'

Comment: It gives me the error of:- incorrect syntax new the keyword 'SELECT'

Comment: This seems like very dangerous code.  Do you know what an `identity` column is?  Do you know what sequences are?  There are probably better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: MAX(ID) + 1 is not a better way, instead that use identity column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses `(   ...   )`:

```
DECLARE @ID int;
SET @ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM tbl);
```

or `SELECT` as [suggested by Giorgi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29148059/284240). `SET` is the ANSI standard way of assigning values to variables, `SELECT` is not. Apart from that using `SELECT` to assign values to variables is fine, it allows even multiple assignments with one `SELECT`.

But in general your query seems to be a race condition. Use an [`IDENTITY` column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) if you want to autoincrement a value.  [Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Comment: Great thanks a lot - sorry, still thumbing my way through sql

Comment: @Tom: not sure what you're doing there, but maybe you should use an `Identity` column instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012 Then this works automatically and you have no race condition.

Comment: I would love to use an identity column, but this table stores lots of versions of the same ID - bad planning when I set it up.

Comment: @Tom then you need to fix it. Slapping more code at a known problem is not a good approach. This is going to cause you nothing but pain in the long run. Setup some sequences, create a table for the identity for each type of version or whatever. MAX(ID) + 1 will end up with duplicates and cause nothing but grief....I speak from experience here.

Comment: I appreciate your points and realise this isn't a good approach but I haven't got the time at the moment to redo the front end of it. I will amend the table in v2.0

Answer (score 4):

No need for `SET`. Select value directly:

```
DECLARE @ID int;
SELECT @ID = MAX(ID) + 1 FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Hi giorgi, I am preparing for `70-461` exam,could you provide aome tipsfor passing the exam? appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider a scenario when there is no value in the table and MAX returns NULL.

```
DECLARE @ID int;

SELECT @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID) , 0) + 1 FROM tbl;
```

Other adding 1 to null will always yield null.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ID int;
SET @ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM tbl);
```

parentheses operator ()

for more information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx