# How to write the query for auto-generated ID

Tags: c#, sql, auto-increment

I get an error when I input the drop down list parameter as data, I could not add the parameter data into the invoice table,the parameter data for subtotal, tax and total got their own value, but it only work well for manually input the data.

Drop down list parameter:

```
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (@subtotal,@tax,@total); select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as invoiceID;";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtotal", subtotal);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", tax);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
object OBJinvoiceID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Manually input:

```
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (2,2,2); select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as invoiceID;";
object OBJinvoiceID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: MySQL or Microsoft SQL?

Comment: If the identity column is set, then you cannot specify a value.  Omit it from the insert and it will work.

Comment: Am I missing something here, or are you inserting into a different table than the one you're creating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the field from your values-listing:

```
insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (@subtotal,@tax,@total); select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as invoiceID;
```

Also you can use the OUTPUT-Clause to get the value using:

```
into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) OUTPUT invoiceID values (@subtotal,@tax,@total);
```

In the case you actually want to set the `identity`-column manually, you can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` as described [here in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Comment: yes, I have tried this before, but I get an error saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'invoiceID', table ; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: the error occur at line "object OBJinvoiceID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: Is the table named `Invoice` or `Order1`? Is there a difference? When your table has the column `invoiceID` as identity-column, it cannot be inserted so it must be left out. Please check the table-configuration and the IDENTITY_INSERT setting.

Comment: there have 2 table, 1 is invoice another 1 is Order1. It works well for Order1 because I input the data manually. But I get the error when I set it as auto-increment, the difference of this table is the data in Order1 table is manually input, but the data in Invoice is I get the parameter from the drop down list

Comment: because I got the parameters "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtotal", subtotal);" in invoice table, so I get the error? how to solve with this?

Comment: It's hard to understand you here, please use more proper English grammar. I see you edited your initial post. If it is that way, you need to specify a value for the invoiceID-column. The initial post showed the Order1-Table which had the corresponding column as IDENTITY. And which column(s) do you mean by "data"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the invoiceID

```
insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (@subtotal,@tax,@total);
```

Comment: yes, I have tried this before, but I get an error saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'invoiceID', table ; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: the error occur at line "object OBJinvoiceID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: I see you have edited your post to show us the code for creating the invoice table. It doesn't have `invoiceID` as an Identity column which is why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it Incrementing in database you dont need to Alter it again in the code. Just remove the invoiceID from your statement

Comment: yes, I have tried this before, but I get an error saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'invoiceID', table ; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: the error occur at line "object OBJinvoiceID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: Rebuild you database implementation so its something like: invoiceID int NOT NULL  and make sure it is set like identity. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012) so you can easily do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a .NET guy, but by googling I think you have to not mention the identity field in your insert query:

```
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (@subtotal,@tax,@total);
// the rest
            }
```

Plz take a look in this simple tutorial:
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: yes, I have tried this before, but I get an error saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'invoiceID', table ; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: the error occur at line "object OBJinvoiceID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (@subtotal,@tax,@total); select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as invoiceID;
```

Comment: yes, I have tried this before, but I get an error saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'invoiceID', table ; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: the error occur at line "object OBJinvoiceID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();"