# Powershell Script to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powershell, database-design

I have this PowerShell script that will collect the system information of my remote servers.

**My problem:** I am not sure how to have this script when running to populate my newly created database `Hal0Test` that I created in SQL Server Management Studio.

**End Goal:** I would like my powershell script to look at the column in the remote server **QAUTILITYDB01** > ServerList (database) > labeled "ServerName" take "QACGAPPSVR01, QACGAPPSVR03, and etc." Push each of those values into my powershell script and generate for each server its FQDN and OS. Lastly, push that new values (FQDN and OS) back to the remote database.

NEW Powershell Script Code:

```
$connectionString = "Server=QAUTILITYDB01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
$command.CommandText = $query
$ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

While ($ServerNames.read()){
    $ServerArray.Add($ServerNames[0])
}

foreach($Server in $ServerArray){
    # $Server returns each server name
    $os    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $_ |
             Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
             ForEach-Object {
                 '{0} {1:D} MB Free/{2:D} MB Used' -f $_.DeviceID,
                     [int]($_.FreeSpace/1MB), [int]($_.Size/1MB)
             }

    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'FQDN'            = $_
      'ServerName'      = $os.PSComputerName
      'OperatingSystem' = $os.Caption
      'Disks'           = $disks -join ' | '
    }
    $command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$os.Caption' WHERE ServerName = '$os.PSComputerName';"
    $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

} Export-Csv 'C:\Desktop\HalO\output.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoType
```

Powershell CSV file:

```
ServerName  FQDN    Disks   OperatingSystem
SVR01   Svr01.xxx.com   C: 17899 MB Free/51097 MB Used | E: 22277 MB Free/25597 MB Used Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 
SVR03   svr03.xxx.com   C: 18280 MB Free/61337 MB Used | E: 50079 MB Free/56317 MB Used Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 
SVR05   svr05.xxx.com   C: 8751 MB Free/40857 MB Used | E: 4987 MB Free/10237 MB Used   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 
SVR06   svr06.xxx.com   C: 14188 MB Free/61337 MB Used | E: 34962 MB Free/56317 MB Used Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 
SVR08   Svr08.xxx.com   C: 6464 MB Free/40857 MB Used | E: 5921 MB Free/10237 MB Used   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "There is already an open DataReader 
associated with this Command which must be closed first."
At C:\Users\mdaraghmeh\Desktop\HalO\test2.ps1:33 char:5
+     $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

**SQL ServerList:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set up your SQL Server connection at the beginning of the script:

```
$connectionString = "Server=ulidb01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
```

To execute a query to update the server:

```
$command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$os.Caption' WHERE ServerName = '$os.PSComputerName';"
$result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

OK--now back to the top to get the list of servernames:

```
$ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
$command.CommandText = $query
$ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

While ($ServerNames.read()){
    $ServerArray.Add($ServerNames[0])
}
```

This will give you an arraylist ($ServerArray) of server names.  So you iterate through this arraylist in an outer loop:

```
foreach($Server in $ServerArray){
    # $Server returns each server name
}
```

...or you could leave it like you have it piped into foreach-object.  I just prefer not to use piping in scripts as it is easier to read.

Then at the end of the script you need to close the SQL Server connection:

```
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Don't build query strings like that. It makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, you need subexpressions for expanding the properties of `$os` inside a string.

Comment: Since he showed output that he's got going to CSV I didn't consider whether $os.PSComputerName was adequate.  And wouldn't someone need to modify what WMI is returning to inject SQL here?  It would seem to me that the system would already be compromised in order to hijack a script like this that is not getting input from an unknown source.

Comment: Yes--as I mentioned in the answer, the ServerID column needs to be auto-generated by SQL Server or you need to set the ID somehow.  I didn't see in your code where you are generating that ID.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012 for how to auto generate it.  If you are creating the ID in your code, then something like `"INSERT INTO ServerLIst (ServerID, ServerName, FQDN, OS) VALUES('$MyId', '$os.PSComputerName', '$_', '$os.Caption');"`

Comment: For updating those two columns, change your query string to `UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$os.Caption' WHERE ServerName = '$os.PSComputerName'`

Comment: ...so now you just need to populate $serverslist from the database... hang on.

Comment: I am now getting a new error for the excel file .csv I removed that line and got another error. Please see new code/error above

Comment: I have faith that you can figure that one out.  It's pretty clear.

Comment: I removed the | from the Export-Csv command but I can not figure out the error: "There is already an open DataReader 
associated with this Command which must be closed first." I have no ExecuteReader in my code only ExecuteNonQuery. Mind giving me a hint? @TonyHinkle

Comment: My guess is that you need to do a $connection.Close() before the line that is giving you that error.  If that doesn't work, I recommend that you create a new question with the new script posted and error details.

Comment: Did not work but I will make a new question! Thank you again!