# INSERT INTO fails due to incorrect conversion T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    TableID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    ForeignID INT NOT NULL,
    Value sql_variant NOT NULL,
    CodeOne VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    CodeTwo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
)
```

I'm trying to do a insert with the following code:

```
    INSERT INTO MyTable(ForeignID, Value, CodeOne, CodeTwo)
    VALUES
    (
        1,
        'FooBar',
        'Foo',
        'Bar'
    )
```

I get the following error in SQL Server Mgmt studio when I try to execute the code above:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'FooBar' to data type int.
```

The only reason why it might be trying to convert 'FooBar' to int if it thinks 1 is the primary key and 'FooBar' is in the position of ForeignID. My understanding of INSERT INTO...VALUES is that you don't need to provide the primary key since it should be auto generated. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm using this page as a reference:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/tsql-understanding-how-to-use-the-insert-statement-to-populate-your-database-tables.html

Any ideas on why 'FooBar' is being converted to an int? Thanks!

### More Info:

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Version Info:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.16384
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.18444
Operating System                        6.1.7601

Comment: Your column _Value _  have type  _sql_variant_  and i think this is simple integer, and you try to  put there varchar type

Comment: Your INSERT statement is OK.  Is there perhaps a trigger on the table?  Code that specifies an integer literal against the sql_variant column will cause this error if you have character data in the column due to implicit conversion.

Comment: The insert statement does look good and should not lead to a conversion of FooBar to int. Try using [] around the names of the columns (like INTO MyTable([ForeignID], [Value], [CodeOne], [CodeTwo]) This prevents SQL from confusing commands and columnnames. Also the use of sql_variant may not be the best choice.

Comment: @SpartaSixZero: You need to add IDENTITY to your primary key column. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012

Comment: The reason we used sql_variant as the type was because Value was designed to store varchars, ints, and bits.

Comment: Please do not change the important information regarding question after somebody answer it . Please keep in mind this , if you can include all the information  when you are asking , in this case your first table structure is different from the structure after edit. Before edit TableID was not identity column, if you editing something in question then atleast mark it as an update

Comment: also one more thing your query is working perfectly in sql server 2008 r2 version with out any casting , which sql version you are using ??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Sorry about that. I should have included everything at the beginning. I understand people's time is precious. I updated sql version in my question.

Comment: when you updating something in question just mention as update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there's no implicit conversion from `varchar` (your literal) to `sql_variant`. Just add an explicit conversion and you're done:

```
cast('FooBar' as sql_variant)
```

Comment: @SpartaSixZero, which version SQL Server you are trying to cause it should work just fine in 2008 R2 and 2012 without any casting.

Comment: @SpartaSixZero, strange!!! cause I just tried in 2012 and it worked just fine. Anyways, Luaan given a nice answer.

Comment: Very strange! Here is my version info: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.16384
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.18444
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: @Rahul It shouldn't help for such a simple `insert` - that should be handled by the implicit conversion just fine. The problem starts when you're using `insert ... select` - the conversion will actually happen long before it gets to the `insert`. Try `insert into @table ([Test]) select 3 union all select 'FooBar'` for example - the unioned selects must have a proper type for their "columns", and the `int` value takes precedence in that. Using `sql_variant` explicitly takes care of that.

Comment: @Luaan, where does `insert into ... select from` coming into picture here. isn't OP doing a direct INSERT query? at least that's what I see from post.

Comment: @Rahul Well, honestly, I've never used `sql_variant` without doing the explicit conversion. There's just too many cases where it doesn't work as I'd like :D The OPs code actually works fine for me on 2008 R2 as well. It might have something to do with the data already in the table, or the query execution planner... the more dynamic you get, the more useful it is to just close your eyes and think of England :D

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is because of primary key constraint on the column. And one important thing to be noted here is, primary cannot be an identity column by default. The reason for failure might be because of sql_variant declaration for value column. It cannot support varchar data types. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173829.aspx . Please try to make the primary column as identity column and Value column as varchar or nvarchar column (based on the scenario) and try insert statement again.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't support `varchar(max)`. It does support e.g. `varchar(6)` just fine.