# Insert column into table and increment row by one

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, max

Given the following tables, I am trying to set `eventid` to the highest value, incremented by one. So `max(eventid) + 1`. I cannot seem to get the right SQL syntax to accomplish this.

What I have right now that works, but does not give me what I need, is the following. How would I get the `eventid` to show, in this case, 96740?

```
INSERT INTO stock_history
            (lastmodby,
             event,
             previous_stock,
             new_stock,
             lastmodified,
             productid)
SELECT '160'                     AS lastmodby,
       'SALE'                    AS event,
       stockstatus               AS previous_stock,
       stockstatus + 1           AS new_stock,
       Getdate()                 AS lastmodified,
       products_joined.productid AS productid
FROM   products_joined
WHERE  productcode = 'abc'
```

stock_history table

```
+--------+-----------+----------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------------------+-----------+
|   id   | productid | previous_stock | count | new_stock | event | eventid |     lastmodified      | lastmodby |
+--------+-----------+----------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------------------+-----------+
| 105619 |      9282 |              9 |     1 |        10 | SALE  |         | 7/24/2015 5:29:00 PM  |       160 |
| 105578 |      9282 |              8 |     1 |         9 | ORDER |   96739 | 7/23/2015 7:30:00 PM  |     37655 |
|  89241 |      9282 |              7 |     1 |         8 | ORDER |   96738 | 6/1/2014 6:06:00 PM   |     30761 |
|  86773 |      9282 |              6 |     1 |         7 | ORDER |   96737 | 4/12/2014 4:36:00 PM  |     29745 |
|  70419 |      9282 |              5 |     1 |         6 | ORDER |   96736 | 5/21/2013 1:17:00 PM  |      1754 |
|  69088 |      9200 |             19 |     1 |        20 | EDIT  |   96735 | 4/28/2013 10:26:00 AM |      1754 |
|  69050 |      9200 |             18 |     1 |        19 | ORDER |   96734 | 4/27/2013 2:17:00 PM  |     23001 |
|  68127 |      9200 |             17 |     1 |        18 | ORDER |   96733 | 4/13/2013 12:34:00 PM |     22674 |
|  67064 |      9200 |             16 |     1 |        17 | ORDER |   96732 | 3/30/2013 9:23:00 AM  |     22327 |
+--------+-----------+----------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

products_joined table

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| productcode | productid | stockstatus |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| abc         |      9282 |           9 |
| xyz         |      9200 |          19 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using an IDENTITY column - SQL Server will take care of this **much** more efficiently than you can, both in terms of performance as in reliability. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012) gives you some options on how to do that, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE stock_history DROP COLUMN eventid
ALTER TABLE stock_history ADD eventid INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

That said, it is technically possible to do this within the query. It might help to know this pattern for situations where an IDENTITY column is not an option.

```
INSERT INTO stock_history
            (lastmodby,
             event,
             previous_stock,
             new_stock,
             lastmodified,
             productid,
             eventid)
SELECT '160'                     AS lastmodby,
       'SALE'                    AS event,
       stockstatus               AS previous_stock,
       stockstatus + 1           AS new_stock,
       Getdate()                 AS lastmodified,
       products_joined.productid AS productid,
       (SELECT MAX(eventid) + 1 FROM stock_history) AS eventid
FROM   products_joined
WHERE  productcode = 'abc'
```

Note that this could lead to duplicate `eventid`s if this query is executed multiple times at once.

Comment: Your caution is duly noted. The ID column already has identity.