# solution for auto increment on update a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input:-

```
id MF SF DF
----------------
1  0  0  0
```

when update a row for MF means it should increment like +1 in sql query

output:-

```
id MF SF DF
----------------
1  1   0  0
```

when updating a MF or SF or DF it have increment 1 by 1 need simple query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Comment: `When update a row for MF ...` means? Update a row for a column?

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic syntax to update a column value by 1 increment

```
Update [Table Name] 
Set MF = MF + 1 
Where id = 1
```