# Use PK of one table as the PK for another

Tags: sql-server, code-first

So I am working on a code first MVC with multiple SQL tables. The first contains basic information for a person `{UID,FNAME,LNAME,DOB,GENDER}` and the others contain data such as `{BOOL1,BOOL2,BOOL3}`. I am using different tables because some data may not be updated as frequently as others, and wish to keep this data separate. Is is acceptable to use the PK of the first table as the PK of the others? And how would I accomplish this without the problem of inserting an identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the scenario -

1. One table is the master and the other table is a type of the first one: in this case the first table PK is FK for the second one. you may still make this field unique and also use it for clustered index if it makes sense.
2. Two tables has different type of objects but should use a shared exclusive ids: in this case you may use a sequence for Id to make them unique.

Comment: Yes, both tables are different types of data. How would I make a sequence for the id?

Comment: Look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012

Comment: Ok, an auto-incremented value. How would i ensure that the IDs of both tables were the same? Create them at one time, then save the changes to the database at one time?

Comment: you specify the same sequence for the id in both tables. you get the next value when inserting - INSERT Test.TestTable (CounterColumn,Name)  
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1, 'Syed') ; ... it means you are not using identity for the field