# Select Scope_Identity fails on live server but not on local database

Tags: sql, asp.net, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
insert into [Order](UserId,MembershipType,PaymentAmt,PaymentStatus,StartDate,EndDate,Status)output INSERTED.OrderId values('18','Yearly','9.99','','2017-02-14 15:13:22','2018-02-14 15:13:22','1');Select Scope_Identity()
```

Which will insert the data in to my dbo.Order table in my Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database locally on my PC.

But when I run this query on a live 3rd party web server (With an identical database table) I get the following error:

```
exception=Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderId', table 'db1128212_MYDATABASE.dbo.Order'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Why is this?

Comment: Even if you say it is identical, it doesn't seem to have an `IDENTITY` column `OrderId`

Answer (score 0):

Set the OrderId column on the remote table to identity/auto increment.

[Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Comment: If it's an identity-column is is auto increment

Comment: I don't believe his primary key is set to identity, see edited answer.