# why ActionResult method parameter is null in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a form to `ActionResult` method but it is null always. 
In fact, I got the error *Value cannot be null.* but I don't know why I got it the error.

Here is `ActionResult` code and my view.

```
public class VocabularyController : Controller
{
    private VocabContext _context;

    public VocabularyController()
    {
        _context = new VocabContext();
    }
    // GET: Vocabulary
    [Route("New")]
    public ActionResult New()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Vocabulary word)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Vocabularies.Add(word);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("dashboard", "Home");
    }



}
```

==============================

```
@model EnglishTest.Models.Vocabulary

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="element-wrapper">
            <h6 class="element-header">New Word Form</h6>
            <div class="element-box">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Vocabulary", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Word)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Word, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Word" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Word)
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Defination)
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Defination, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Definition" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Defination)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Synonym)
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Synonym, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Synonym" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Synonym)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PersianTranslate)
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.PersianTranslate, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Persian Translation" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PersianTranslate)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Examples)
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Examples, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Examples" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Examples)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                <div class="form-buttons-w"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Save</button></div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

==============================

```
   public class Vocabulary
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Word { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Defination { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Synonym { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PersianTranslate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Examples { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what is your controller name

Comment: @HakamFostok,it is Vocabulary.

Comment: did you checked the value of id??

Comment: @serious_s I didn't check.

Comment: since this is a primary key, it can't be null, even if you make it nullable. also check your action method whether it is post/get? because here you are sending a post request, But .net mvc form has built in get request .

Comment: @serious_s, how to initialize Id that is a primary key?

Comment: as i can see you are using EF.. if it is code first approach you can do it normally like u did. after that go to mssql server and go to table find the id column and mark it as an index. you can also visit the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012

Answer (score 2):

I Changed the input parameter to my model name, it works fine.

```
public ActionResult Save(Vocabulary vocabulary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a post to the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Vocabulary", FormMethod.Post))
```

Also the second `@` is not requried:

```
Html.BeginForm("Save", "Vocabulary", FormMethod.Post)
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your entire cshtml code.

Comment: I updated my cshtml code.

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: It was my problem when I copy and paste in here.there is not my code.

Comment: Also try using `<input type="submit" />` instead of `button`.

Comment: It doesn't work.