# How do i get the highest ID number of a table and increment it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the highest ID number in the table and increment it but it seems to return 0 with how i'm doing it.

```
private int MaxAuthorValue()
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Library;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string maxQuery = "SELECT MAX(AuthorId) FROM Author";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(maxQuery, connection);
        int x = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        return x + 1;
    }
}
```

What I want to do with this is return the inremented ID so that the user can add an Author and doesnt have to write in the ID themself, as that would be pretty unsafe to do (for example if an author have ID=1 and they try to add another author with the same ID number it would create an error.)

Edit: Adding SQLServer table creation code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Author] 
(
    [AuthorId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Nationality] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuthorId] ASC)
);
```

Comment: _"doesnt seem to work"_ it's not a right way to describe problem. What you expect to get and what you get?

Comment: Don't increment the value yourself.  Use an `identity` column.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited it with a better explanation now

Comment: For what purpose are you doing this?  It's entirely possible for this value to change after you read it, so you need Transactions to be safe.  It's also entirely possible that you don't need to do this, as databases handle autoincrement / identity columns natively.

Comment: "What is a purpose" is a secondary question, first let's explain him, why is he getting wrong value, then explain that there is other ways to reach that result.

Comment: Updated with the purpose

Comment: @anek05 - As you say that this is for inserting a new row with a new and unique id, ***Don't Do It This Way***.  Check out `IDENTITY` columns in SQL Server.  SQL Server then allocates the new id for you, and you avoid race conditions and a hundred other problems.

Comment: Do you want the user to enter the ID or auto generate it automatically so that no two users have the same ID?

Comment: The later, i want to auto generate it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table isn't very big yet, I would suggest you to drop and recreate the table with

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.<YOUR-TABLE-NAME>
(
  Id int NOT NULL
         IDENTITY(1, 1),
  --Other Column names and types
)
ON  [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If not, then add a new column and use it as your ID

```
ALTER <YOUR-TABLE-NAME>
ADD <NEW-ID-COLUMN-NAME> INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
GO
```

And then delete your existing ID column

Edit: You are also trying to insert value for the Identity Column. You should not insert any value for `AuthorId`. That is you should just insert values for the remaining columns except `AuthorId`.

Comment: How do i turn on IDENTITY_INSERT? 

I get "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table Author when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

       `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Author] (
        [AuthorId]    INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
        [Name]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [Nationality] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuthorId] ASC)
    );`

Comment: Can you post the SQL code that you used to create the table?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Author] (
    [AuthorId]    INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Nationality] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuthorId] ASC)
);`

Comment: I see the error you're making. I'm adding additional information to my answer

Comment: Thanks this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IDENT_CURRENT('<tablename>')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql) to get the last provided identity of that table

It will give you the last one ***over all scopes and sessions*** which is important - other users might have open transactions with new inserts in theire session. A `select max(id_column) from ...` works by default only in in your session.

If you want the next id, use [IDENT_INCR ( 'table_or_view' )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-incr-transact-sql)

Much smarter is an automaticly assigned ID - you just dont provide the ID column in your `insert` and SqlServer does the right thing for you: 
Autoincrementing Identities, see f.e. here: [Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Comment: I would welcome feedback with downvotes  - I might adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: I feel that your answer is the closest to what the OP asked. What he originally wanted was to have no duplicate IDs in the AuthorID column and I believe he didn't realise something like marking  a column as `Identity` existed.