# I have 10 employee and real time data is coming, while I need to insert each records equally distribution (Insert records)

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server Query help: I have **10 employees** and **real time data is coming**, while I need to **Insert** each records equally distribution.

Example:

> Data=1 then EmployeeId=1, Next time Data=2 should be Insert to
>   EmployeeId=2 and this cycle will continue as per received raw data.

Comment: Use an identity column as your EmployeeId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Comment: I may be reading this wrong, but I get the impression that the OP is trying to do a "Round-Robin" type of data assignment. If that is the case, it should be a fairly simple task using the modulo operator (%). Give me a few mins and I'll post an example...

Comment: Probably modulo of the number of operators currently logged-in ??  What happens when all but one calls in sick?  The other assignments just sit there?  Or when 2 employees quit? Then they sit there forever?  It is better to have just ONE QUEUE, and when employee needs one just gets the next unassigned item and assigns it to theirself.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE tempdb;
GO

/* Just setting up some tables to test with... */
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT pk_Employee
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    FirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DepartmentID TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PrimaryJobTitle VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    );
GO 

/* Note: I'm assuming that only a certain subset of employees will be assigned "data".
    In this case, those employees are in department 4, with a primary jobt itle of "Do Stuff"... */
INSERT dbo.Employee (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, DepartmentID, PrimaryJobTitle) VALUES
    ( 1, 'Jane', 'Doe', 1, 'CEO'),
    ( 2, 'Alex', 'Doe', 2, 'CIO'),
    ( 3, 'Bart', 'Doe', 3, 'CFO'),
    ( 4, 'Cami', 'Doe', 4, 'COO'),
    ( 5, 'Dolt', 'Doe', 3, 'Accountant'),
    ( 6, 'Elen', 'Doe', 4, 'Production Manager'),
    ( 7, 'Flip', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    ( 8, 'Gary', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    ( 9, 'Hary', 'Doe', 2, 'App Dev'),
    (10, 'Jill', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (11, 'Kent', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (12, 'Lary', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (13, 'Many', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (14, 'Norm', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (15, 'Paul', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (16, 'Qint', 'Doe', 3, 'Accountant'),
    (17, 'Ralf', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (18, 'Saul', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (19, 'Tony', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff'),
    (20, 'Vinn', 'Doe', 4, 'Do Stuff');
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.WorkAssignment (
    WorkAssignmentID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_WorkAssignment
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    WorkOrder INT NOT NULL,
    AssignedTo INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_WorkAssignment_AssignedTo
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Employee(EmployeeID)
    );
GO
```

--===================================================================

```
/* This is where the actual solution begins... */

/*
Blindly assigning work orders in “round-robin” order is pretty simple but probably not applicable to the real world.
It seems unlikely that all employees who will be assigned work will all have their EmployeeIDs assigned 1 - N without any gaps… 
If new work assignments were to start at 1 every time, the employees with low number IDs would end up being assigned more work 
    than those with the highest IDs… and… if “assignment batches” tend to be smaller than the employee count, employees with 
    high ID numbers may never get any work assigned to them.

This solution deals with both potential problems by putting the “assignable” employees into a #EmployAssignmentOrder table where 
    the AssignmentOrder guarantees a clean unbroken sequence of numbers, no matter the actual EmployeeID values, and picks up 
    where the last assignment left off.
*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmployAssignmentOrder', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #EmployAssignmentOrder;

CREATE TABLE #EmployAssignmentOrder (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL,
    AssignmentOrder INT NOT NULL 
    );

DECLARE 
    @LastAssignedTo INT = ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1) wa.AssignedTo FROM dbo.WorkAssignment wa ORDER BY wa.WorkAssignmentID DESC), 0),
    @AssignableEmpCount INT = 0;

INSERT #EmployAssignmentOrder (EmployeeID, AssignmentOrder)
SELECT 
    e.EmployeeID,
    AssignmentOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN e.EmployeeID <= @LastAssignedTo THEN e.EmployeeID * 1000 ELSE e.EmployeeID END )
FROM
    dbo.Employee e
WHERE 
    e.DepartmentID = 4
    AND e.PrimaryJobTitle = 'Do Stuff';

SET @AssignableEmpCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

ALTER TABLE #EmployAssignmentOrder ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AssignmentOrder);

/* Using an "inline tally" to generate new work orders...  
This won’t be part of you final working solution BUT you should recognize the fact that we are relying on the the fact that the 
    ROW_NUMBER() function is generating an ordered number sequence, 1 - N...You’ll need to generate a similar sequence in your 
    production solution as well.
*/
WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_Tally (n) AS (
        SELECT TOP (1999)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b
        )
INSERT dbo.WorkAssignment (WorkOrder, AssignedTo)
SELECT 
    WorkOrder = t.n + DATEDIFF(SECOND, '20180101', GETDATE()),
    eao.EmployeeID
FROM
    cte_Tally t
    JOIN #EmployAssignmentOrder eao
        ON ISNULL(NULLIF(t.n % @AssignableEmpCount, 0), @AssignableEmpCount) = eao.AssignmentOrder;

-- Check the newly inserted values...
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dbo.WorkAssignment wa
ORDER BY 
    wa.WorkAssignmentID;
```

--===================================================================

```
-- cleanup...
/*
DROP TABLE dbo.WorkAssignment;
DROP TABLE dbo.Employee;
DROP TABLE #EmployAssignmentOrder;
*/
```