# Sql Identity Inserting Value Only 0 in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2

I try using Sql Identity in my table for No column. If I try insert value from table with c#, always insert "0" and Identity not working. How can I fix this?

```
SqlCommand Cmd_IdentityOpen;
string SqlIdentityOpen = "SET identity_insert " + cbbox_ltable.Text + " on";
SqlIdentityOpen += " INSERT INTO " + cbbox_ltable.Text + " ([No], [Computer ID], [Name Surname] ) Values ('" + txtbox_lno.Text + "' , '" + cbbox_lcid.Text + "' , '" + txtbox_lnamesurname.Text + "' )";
Cmd_IdentityOpen = new SqlCommand(SqlIdentityOpen, con);
con.Open();
Cmd_IdentityOpen.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Table Code

```
SqlTableCreate += "CREATE TABLE " + txtbox_ltablename.Text + " ([No] int not null IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, [Computer ID] nvarchar(50), [Name Surname] nvarchar(50) )";
```

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... ON` says to the system that *you* are taking responsibility for inserting identity values, rather than relying on the system to do so.

Comment: Set column No int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,  the starting value for IDENTITY is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012

Comment: I need use that code, because if I can't use I get error like this : "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TableName' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: If you want SQL Server to use identity for the `No` column, why are you *also* trying to insert a value yourself into that column?

Comment: This code's main problem is not identity but SQL injection attack which is a much bigger problem.  And the two problems might be connected, parse the values using parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users can and do supply the `[No]` value, then: it isn't an `IDENTITY` in the SQL Server sense (it could still be a primary key, though, etc); so decide:

- if you want it to be an `IDENTITY`, don't let the users provide it, don't include it in the `INSERT`, and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to find out what you got *after* inserting
- if you don't need it to be an `IDENTITY`, don't declare it as one

Mixing and matching rarely works.

Unrelated, but you **really, really** need to look into SQL injection and parameterization; that code is *actively dangerous*. A safe command is something more like:

```cs
cmd.CommandText @"
INSERT INTO YourTable ([Computer ID], [Name Surname])
VALUES (@id, @name);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cbbox_lcid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtbox_lnamesurname.Text);
var newId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thanks for help :) I wanna Ask one more question. If I delete Identity number like 8, its start insert value from 9. How can I start Identity number 8?

Comment: @Destiny you can't and shouldn't; that isn't how an identity works; you don't reuse them - otherwise when someone asks for "record 8", you don't know whether they mean "the old record 8, that was deleted, and I should report 'not found'", vs "the new record 8"; the *really* fun bit is: an identity can be issued but rolled back in a transaction, so it is entirely normal and expected for there to be gaps occasionally