# How can I remove the ID column from a local sql table or change it to AUTO INCREMENT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlclient, server-explorer

I want to get rid of the ID column I added to a local sql table.

When I deleted the column from the designer and tried to Update, I got this:

[image]

Another option would be to make the ID column AUTO INCREMENT by changing it to "[Id]           INT        NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,", but I also got an error when I added that to the table definition and selected Update.

Even when I change the Table back to what it is (add the ID column back) like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsToIgnore] (
    [Id]           INT        NOT NULL,
    [WordToIgnore] NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Source]       NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

...I still get the err msg when I try to Update...

Comment: Which database is this? Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @tadman: Yes, the local db that comes with Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Did you create that table or was it there?  Does the table contain data? Any other table which depends on the data (id column) of this table ? Do you have management studio?

Comment: Did you drop the primary key constraint on the column before trying to drop it or change its type?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Yes, and it threw an exception then, too. I'm just going to create another table, sans ID, and use that. I don't need no stinkin' ID, as the Bandolero in "Treasure of the Sierra Madre" said (or something like that).

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage: I have Server Explorer; I created the table. I created the ID out of habit, and assumed it would be an AutoInc situation, but it's not.

Comment: There are probably a chain of constraints that need to be dropped: if you had a primary key constraint on dbo.WordsToIgnore.Id then you probably have foreign key constraints referencing that. A new table won't fix that - you'll have to drop the FK constraints and recreate them referencing the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to define Column as given below. [MSDN REFERENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> ```
> <column_definition> ::= column_name <data_type>
> [ FILESTREAM ]
> [ COLLATE collation_name ]
> [ SPARSE ]
> [ MASKED WITH ( FUNCTION = ' mask_function ') ]
> [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name [ DEFAULT constant_expression ] ]
> [ IDENTITY [ ( seed,increment ) ]
> [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ]
> [ GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW { START | END } [ HIDDEN ] ]
> [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
> [ ROWGUIDCOL ]
> [ ENCRYPTED WITH
>     ( COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = key_name ,
>       ENCRYPTION_TYPE = { DETERMINISTIC | RANDOMIZED } ,
>       ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256'
>     ) ]
> [ <column_constraint> [, ...n ] ]
> [ <column_index> ]
> ```

So, here it is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsToIgnore] (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_WordsToIgnore PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [WordToIgnore] NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Source]       NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Or you can define constraint in a separate line

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsToIgnore] (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    [WordToIgnore] NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Source]       NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_WordsToIgnore PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012), the following should do the trick:

```
[Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

(IOW, intrude the "IDENTITY(1,1)" jazz between "NULL" and "PRIMARY KEY"