# Increment variable in Foreach-Object

Tags: sql, powershell

I want insert some AD attributes with PowerShell into a SQL table. So far so good:

```bsh
$insert = @'
    INSERT INTO [mdb].[dbo].[import](id,userid)
    VALUES ('{0}','{1}')
'@
 
Try {
    
    $connectionString = 'Data Source=serverdb;Initial Catalog=mdb;Integrated Security=SSPI'
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()

    $counter = 0

    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=company,DC=company,DC=state,DC=de" | Select @{Name="ID";Expression={ $global:counter; $global:counter++ }},SamAccountName |`
        ForEach-Object  {           
            $cmd.CommandText = $insert -f $counter,$_.SamAccountName
            $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }

    $conn.Close()
}
Catch {
    Throw $_
}
```

The output from get-ADUser is right, but the insert throws an error, that the primary key has duplicates. The incrementing must be wrong.

Can anybody help? THANKS!

Comment: Your query is open to SQL Injections. Use parameters for your query, not string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

ID is starting from 1 and not 0, is this normal ?

Furthermore, why are you creating an user defined property (ID) and don't use it ?

You can avoid the ugly global scope too (starting counter from 0 here) :

```
#### $counter = 0     <--- No more usefull

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=company,DC=company,DC=state,DC=de" | Select SamAccountName |`
ForEach-Object -Begin { $counter = 0 } -Process {
            $cmd.CommandText = $insert -f $counter,$_.SamAccountName
            $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            $counter++
            }
```

I am not an SQL specialist, so this is probably not an anwser. But, you have here a nicer code ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Thats the way i used before. It starts with 0 but for the further entries it seems that is is not incrementing: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ... Cannot insert duplicate key in object '.The duplicate key value is (0).

Comment: When you run text formatting only (`$insert -f $counter,$_.SamAccountName`) and `$counter++`, the string result is incrementing well. Have you tried a debug to check if the CommandText is valid before `$cmd` executes the request ? I'm afraid I cannot help more about this

Comment: I guess that the key(s) simply still exist, you better fix this from the SQL side and [Auto increment primary key in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10992074/1701026) (or is this already on, and you also try to manually set this?)

Answer (score 0):

You should always use **parameters** when inserting data with SQL. ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)) In short: It's more secure, more performant, more robust and easier to use.

Put parentheses around the operation `(++$counter)` to return the value after increasing it. (Use `$counter++` if you want zero-based ids, `++$counter` if you want 1-based ids.)

```bsh
$cmd.CommandText = "
    INSERT INTO [mdb].[dbo].[import](id,userid)
    VALUES (@id, @userId)
"
$counter = 0
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=company,DC=company,DC=state,DC=de" | foreach {
    $cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", (++$counter))
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userId", $_.SamAccountName)
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```