# Inserting values from another table into a column where values are null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A with ID's only and another table B with two columns, ID and Product Number. The ID column in table B has nulls and Product Number has Product Numbers. I would like to update table B with the ID's in column in no specific order just so that the Product Number has ID's.

I have tried to use update but that has not worked, have tried insert but it just adds the ID's in A to the bottom of the list in B. Would like to do this in Microsoft SQL.

SQL code tried:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProductNum') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ProductNum

SELECT  ID
INTO    #ProductNum
FROM    Products

    

UPDATE  [ProductCatalogue] PC
SET
PC.ID = Pn.ID
FROM #ProductNum Pn
INNER JOIN 
[ProductCatalogue] PC   
ON Pc.ID = Pn.ID
WHERE Pc.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above syntax is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Sever

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like you would be better off having the ID-Column Autoincrement, instead of giving it the IDs from table A. This is already explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10992074/14654948) answer.

In case you actually need the specific IDs from table A, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match) SO thread might help you.

Comment: The ID in this case was just an example but the ID am working with can not be auto incremented as I need to take the ID from a master table. The second option might work, however the the ID's in A have no match in table B as Table B just has the ID column but has NULL's in that column. So i pretty much want to assign the ID's in A to the product numbers in table B

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by creating auto increment columns on each table and called it `Row_ID`. Then I used `Row_ID` to join the tables together with some logic provided by @Chris above.